# Update function in Pouchdb using AngularJS Todo App

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I am working on an Todo App Example to get some knowledge about the feutures in Pocudb. 
I have worked on this todo app using AngularJS. I am able to make a todo with a textfield and a radio button. Theese todoes is shown in the ui above the input.

I need to be able to update the radiobutton or textfield in an already existing todo.

There is an add and remove function :

```
 return {
    todos: todos,
    add: function(text,fundkategori) {
      return pouch.post({
        type: 'todo',
        text: text,
        Fundkategori: fundkategori
      }).then(util.resolve)
        .catch(util.reject);
    },



    remove: function(todo) {
      return pouch.get(todo._id)
        .then(function(doc) {
          return pouch.remove(doc)
            .then(util.resolve, util.reject);
        })
        .catch(util.reject);
    }
  };
```

but is guess there should be some update function as well which takes the todo._id

I have a Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/xMdPJ59TG1HgVVYjoVE6?p=preview

// Simon

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly the problem is? What error are you seeing? What do you expect to see?

Comment: I solved it by making an update: function(). I will make a plunker and make this to an Q&A with more details.